# Why can't I test which.max() against 0

Tags: r

I am trying to compare the result of which.max against 0 to check if any maximum value was found in the data. For explanation: There are about 24.000 vectors I must check for their maximum's index.

Here is a litte example:

```
tmp <- which.max(c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
str(tmp)
tmp == 0
as.integer(tmp) == 0
as.numeric(tmp) == 0
```

It results in FALSE, FALSE, and FALSE - although str(tmp) returns int(0).

What I did as workaround is this:

```
tmp <- which.max(c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
isTRUE(as.logical(tmp))
```

This works in differenetiation if which.max() found a maximum or not. However I do not understand why the above comparisons do not work.

Bonus question: Is there another function than str() that had easily shown me the tmp object's structure to instantly understand the comparison fail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int(0)` means it's a *zero-length* vector (i.e. it has no elements, it's empty, etc.).  Even if you do something like `tmp == integer(0)` you get a zero-length logical vector, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

According to `?which.max`:

> Value:
>
> ```
>  Missing and ‘NaN’ values are discarded.
>
>  an ‘integer’ of length 1 or 0 (iff ‘x’ has no non-‘NA’s), giving
>  the index of the _first_ minimum or maximum respectively of ‘x’.
> ```

So you want to check to see whether `length(tmp) > 0`.

Comment: Thanks! I had read the manual section you cite, but I over-read the "length"... An of course, I didn't get that int(0) could mean "0" elements instead of integer with value "0". So easy if you know where to look...

Answer (score 3):

You can whether tmp is `numeric(0)` as:

```
length(tmp) == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be better if `which.max` returned `0` or `-1` when no max value was found. Then you could more easily check it. `regexpr` for instance returns `-1` and `match` allows you to specify what is returned in the case of no match (which this arguably is similar to).

...but you can check the return value's length yourself:

```
x <-  which.max(c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
if(length(x)) {
  # Do stuff with x...
}
```

...or wrap it into a function to simplify things:

```
which.max2 <- function(x) {
    x <-  which.max(x)
    if(length(x)) x else 0L
}

which.max2(c(NA,-Inf,NA)) # 2
which.max2(c(NA,NA))      # 0
```

Comment: Can you expand on why you think it would be better to return `0L` instead of `integer(0)`?

Comment: Returning `-1` would be very bad because `foo[which.max(foo)]` would return everything except the first element if there was no match.  Returning `0` might make sense because `foo[0L]` and `foo[integer(0)]` would be the same.  `regexpr` is a bit different, since it returns the starting location of the match _within_ each element...